# npm ERR! code EPERM while installing vue-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vue-cli

**When i run npm install -g vue-cli , it continuously throws this error message:**

[image: Screen shot]

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\node_modules\nan\package.json
>   npm ERR! code EPERM
>   npm ERR! errno -4048
>   npm ERR! syscall unlink
>   npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\node_modules\nan\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\node_modules\nan\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\node_modules\nan\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
>   npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-cli\node_modules\nan\package.json' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-10T06_15_03_457Z-debug.log

- **I tried all the possible solutions found online :**

  - **running from windows cmd with administrator access,**
  - **npm cache clean**
  - **closed my text editor**
  - **restarted my PC**

Please do help me solve this issue.

Comment: Anyway try disabling your anti-virus

Comment: You have a reason et the end of the error: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Answer (score 1):

i also had issues on my mac, but maybe here are some hints to help you

1. goto folder: C:\Users\End User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules (in windows make sure to enable all folders)
2. move folders **@vue** and **vue-cli** to trash (previous versions)
3. run cmd.exe as administrator !
4. npm install @vue/cli -g

hopefully this trick will work for you, see
[Mac OS : Install vue cli does work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005638/mac-os-install-vue-cli-does-work-properly) for my answer on the issue with a mac

thx