# Mac OS : Install vue cli does work properly

Tags: macos, vue.js, command-line-interface, vue-cli

I installed `vue-cli` running the following command:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
/Users/me/npm/bin/vue -> /Users/me/npm/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
/Users/me/npm/lib
└── @vue/cli@3.0.0-rc.3
```

When I run vue init, get an the error: "command not found":

```
vue init webpack vue-app
-bash: vue: command not found
```

`vue-cli` does not seem to be in my PATH. When I check the PATH, it includes the directory /Users/me/npm/lib. Here is the result of echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/me/npm/bin/ng:/Users/me/npm/lib:/usr/bin/local/bin:/Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Users/me/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try running the install command with `sudo`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my MacBook Pro (macOS High Sierra, Node 10.4.1, vue-cli 3.0.0-rc.3). I'm using [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) though.

Comment: your `PATH` does't include `/Users/me/npm/bin`, is `/Users/me/npm/bin/ng`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding this to your `$PATH`:

```
/Users/me/npm/bin
```

Your `$PATH` currently goes one level deeper than this, in which case wouldn’t see the content of `bin`.

Answer (score 6):

The same issue occurred for me when running:

**npm install -g @vue/cli**

After much research and experimentation the only thing that worked instead was:

**npm install -g @vue/cli@latest**

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks this worked for me with sudo npm install -g @vue/cli@latest

Comment: This helped! For some reason, `npm search vue` did not present `@vue/cli` so seeing it mentioned here was the missing puzzle piece.

Answer (score 3):

i had a sort a like issue on my mac, my problem was that i already had an old version installed, here are the stips i did to make it work:

1. goto folder: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ (in finder, choose go and then folder)
2. move folders @vue and vue-cli to trash
3. sudo npm install @vue/cli -g
4. enter you admin password

works like charm

Comment: For the note, vue-cli installation pages currently says "You should always avoid running npm with root privileges because install scripts can be unintentionally malicious." https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 2):

For me worked this steps:

1. Find the directory path to where vue-cli was installed. Mine was located here [replace username with yours] `/Users/username/.npm-packages/bin`
2. Open up your bash profile: `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add the following: `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[username]/.npm-packages/bin` replacing [username] with your username.
4. Save the file and restart terminal.
5. You can now use `vue` in terminal as expected.

Comment: Worked like a charm. My was under /Users/[username]/.npm-global/bin

Answer (score 1):

For Mojave, after much struggling, I copied the installed path for `@vue/cli`

1. Path [during installation path is shown]

   ```
   /Users/{your_username}/
   ```

   ```
   .npm-global/bin
   ```
2. Open the GUI with:

   ```sh
   sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   ```
   enter your password
   ```
3. Paste the copied path as

   ```sh
   export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your_username}/ .npm-global/bin
   ```
4. Run:

   ```sh
   vue --version
   ```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `yarn`? try to install `yarn` and run `yarn global add @vue/cli` for me it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you still have same problem and not only with vue cli, but any packages that must be installed globaly by NPM. For me helped:

**brew uninstall node**

And load Node.js as .dmg from official web-site https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and install from it.

After did **sudo npm install -g @vue/cli** and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using **npm** the following worked for me:

1. Open your terminal anywhere and write `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Write the following in the file: `export PATH="$PATH:$(npm config get prefix)/bin"`
3. Press **Ctrl+X** to exit, then **Y** to save the file and hit **Enter** to go back to terminal

You may now be able to call `vue` from terminal. I'm also assuming you've installed the package globally (`npm install -g @vue/cli`)

Answer (score 0):

add `sudo` before those commands, it should work, I have the same issue. You need to give the permission.

Examples:

```
sudo cnpm install vue-cli -g  
sudo cnpm install webpack -g
```